# Selenium WebDriver - Unable to connect to Mozilla geckodriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-5, geckodriver

I am not able to run automation cases any longer since last time I set up the Centos 7 server things worked very well with the Bitbucket repo and I have the exact repo cloned and am not able to run the this time, please if you can help?

My Gem File is below:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org' git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails' gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
# Use Puma as the app server gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console   gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw] end

group :development do   # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.   gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'   gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'   # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring   gem 'spring'   gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0' end

gem 'rspec'

group :test do   
# Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
# Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome 
gem 'chromedriver-helper'
gem 'geckodriver-helper'
gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'rspec-retry'
gem 'rubyXL' 
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data 
gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I have tried all the version till 3.12.0 from the [change log][1], but still get the same error every time which is as below:

```
  unable to connect to Mozilla geckodriver 127.0.0.1:4444 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

It has been more then half day but not able to find a suitable solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

May be useful, I got a solution after 2 weeks when the bundle update updated some of the gems and then the Chrome and Frirefox browser were launched successfully.